# Visual Studio: Automatically re-order page events according to the ASP.NET Page LifeCycle?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, page-lifecycle

What would be the easiest way to re-order existing page events according to the ASP.NET Page LifeCycle?

I'm trying to make my events more readable and maybe make it easy to scroll into a sequentially near event.

If there's no easy way, is there a non-mouse way to quickly switch to a page event without having to type the actual event in incremental search?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is using the code window navigator. To not use the mouse you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then hit tab to tab to the method drop down, and you can use the arrows, including hitting a letter to move in the list and hit enter to select.